# Writing to a div from a form when enter is pressed

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a terminal like website. I had it working before, then stupidly I deleted a bit of code which made the whole thing stop working. I have html, css, and javascript files. I have checked that the input is working and the if statements are working and they are. I really have no idea what's up.

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="cli.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="cli.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="console"></div>

    <form>
      <input type="text" id="input" onkeypress="checkKey()">
    </form>  
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var input=""
function checkKey(){
  var code = event.keyCode;
  if(code == 13) {
    input = document.getElementById("input").value;

    if (input=="help") {
      document.getElementById("console").innerHTML="<p>HELP GOES HERE</p>";
      alert(input)

    } else {
      document.getElementById("console").innerHTML="<p> Invalid command type help for list of commands</p>";
    }
  }
}

function writeToConsole(whatToWrite) {
  document.getElementById("console").innerHTML="<p>"+whatToWrite+"</p>";
}

var objDiv = document.getElementById("console");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

CSS:

```
body{
  background:black;
  color:green;
}
div#console{
  outline: 1px solid white;
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  color:green;
}
input{
  outline: 1px solid white;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  color: green;
  height: 10%;
  font-size: 20pt;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the input is within the a form, the enter key is causing a submit event, so to prevent it return false from the keypress event handler in case of enter key.

Also you will have to pass the `event` object to the handler method from the inline handler.

Also `objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;` will result in an error since your script is loaded in the header(because when it is executed the dom element is not yet created) so move that to a window load handler.

```
<div id="console"></div>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="input" onkeypress="return checkKey(event)" />
</form>
```

then

```
var input = "";

function checkKey(event) {
    var code = event.keyCode;
    if (code == 13) {
        input = document.getElementById("input").value;

        if (input == "help") {
            writeToConsole("<p>HELP GOES HERE</p>");
            alert(input)
        } else {
            writeToConsole("<p> Invalid command type help for list of commands</p>");
        }

        //need to return false as the form will get submitted else
        return false;
    }
}

function writeToConsole(whatToWrite) {
    document.getElementById("console").innerHTML = "<p>" + whatToWrite + "</p>";
}

//need to execute it after the dom is loaded
window.onload = function () {
    var objDiv = document.getElementById("console");
    objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g0rrj5bz/)